# Authors' name in scshape with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In a bibliography, I'd like to have all authors' names in scshape -
I mean even the initials. PLease, consider this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,classical=true,%
firstinits=true,volnumformat=strings,volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,%
indexing]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection]{author}%
{\textsc\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}
    \nocite{*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ bertelli:2012,
       author    = "Lucio Bertelli",
       title     = "Tra storia e utopia",
       publisher = "Edizioni dell'Orso",
       location  = "Alessandria",
       year      = "2012",
     }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Well, the string

```
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection]{author}%
    {\textsc\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}
```

does produce no result. So, what have I to do? Thanx!

Comment: `\textsc\MakeTextLowercase{#1}` is nonsense, as it would take `\MakeTextLowercase` as the argument to `\textsc`.

Comment: I used the code from Classicthesis; in any case you're right. But, even if I use `\mkbibemph` (to try another format), I've no results

Comment: Doesn't the option `scauthors` do what you want?

Comment: No, I wrote above «all authors' names in scshape - I mean even the initials»

Comment: The initials should be uppercase!

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I was posting while you were commenting!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to uncapitalize names.

Comment: @bernard. Maybe. But, for example, one of the most distinguished Italian publisher (Einaudi) uses all scshape for authors' names in bibliographies (initials too are not capitalized). In any case, I'm interested in this question from a TeXnician point of view, and I'd like to understand which solution can be adopted

Comment: @user41063: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The code `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` works fine. I'm looking for an analogue code to change the authors' names format. I know `scauthors`, but it leaves initials capitalized!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the option `scauthors` to have authors names in small caps both in bibliography and citations. You also can choose `scauthorsbib` or `scauthorscite`. Cf; §8, p.6 of the documentation of `biblatex-philosophy`.

[image]

If you absolutely want to use small caps for the whole names, you have to redefine what happens when you set the `scauthors` option and replace `\texsc` with the `\textlcsc` command, borrowed from a post from @Gonzalo Medina:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} 
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,classical=true,scauthors = true, %
firstinits=true,volnumformat=strings,volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,%
indexing]{biblatex}
    \nocite{*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ bertelli:2012,
       author = {Lucio Bertelli},
       title = {Tra storia e utopia},
       publisher = {Edizioni dell'Orso},
       location = {Alessandria},
       year = {2012},
     }
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\iftoggle{bbx:scauthors}{%
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
     \ifblank{#3#5}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}%
  {}}%

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh thanx! a not so easy solution, but works fine