# Authors name in scshape in footnote (with Biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

Referring to my question at the address
[Authors' name in scshape with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214897/authors-name-in-scshape-with-biblatex), for the sake of homogeneity I'd like to have authors' name all in scshape in footnotes too. The relevant code might to be the following one:

```
\AtEveryCite{
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
     \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}%
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
```

but it doesn't work. Please, consider the fullcode (containing the previous definition of `\newcommand\textlcsc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[type1]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[heightrounded]{geometry}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{textcase}

%%% BIBLIOGRAFIA
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,scauthors=true,classical=true,%
firstinits=true,volnumformat=strings,volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,citepages=omit,%
indexing]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}} % riviste tra virgolette caporali
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}} % riviste tra virgolette caporali
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize} % riduce il font della bibliografia

% inverte cognome/nome in philosophy-verbose
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\iftoggle{bbx:scauthorsbib}{%
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textsc}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
     \ifblank{#3#5}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}%
  {}}%
\DeclareNameAlias{last-first/first-last}{first-last}

% rende gli autori in tutto maiuscoletto nella bibliografia
\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\iftoggle{bbx:scauthors}{%
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
     \ifblank{#3#5}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}%
  {}}%

% rende gli autori in tutto maiuscoletto nelle note
\AtEveryCite{
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}%
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}

% mantiene il nome autore nelle citazioni successiva alla prima
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{% 
\ifcase\value{uniquename}% 
\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
 \or 
 \ifuseprefix 
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}} 
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
 \or
 \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}% 
\fi 
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% ridefinisco il formato per usare il numero dell'edizione in apice
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\textsuperscript{#1}}
    {#1\isdot\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}
% imposto l'ordine (e i separatori) dei dati
    \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit}
% elimino la prima occorrenza del campo "edition"
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand{\replaceedition}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {}%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to patch driver #1}}
}
\replaceedition{book}
\replaceedition{collection}
\replaceedition{inbook}
\replaceedition{incollection}
\replaceedition{manual}    
% aggiungo le specifiche per philosophy-verbose
\xpatchbibmacro{incollection:full}
  {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {}%
    {}
    {}
\xpatchbibmacro{book:full}
  {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {}%
    {}
    {}
\xpatchbibmacro{inbook:full}
  {\printfield{edition}%
     \newunit}
    {}%
    {}
    {}

% sostituisce <(a cura di),> con <, a cura di>
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  editor             =  {a cura di},%
  editors            =  {a cura di},%
}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}{\setunit{\addspace}}{\setunit{\addcomma\space}}{}{}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ fornero:2008,
  author         = "Giovanni Fornero",
  title          = "Laicità debole e laicità forte",
  publisher      = "B. Mondadori",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2008",
}

@book{ fornero:2009a,
  author         = "Giovanni Fornero",
  title          = "Bioetica cattolica e bioetica laica",
  publisher      = "B. Mondadori",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2009",
  edition    = "2",
}

@inbook{ fornero:2009b,
  author         = "Giovanni Fornero",
  title          = "Due significati irrinunciabili di laicità",
  booktitle  = "La laicità vista dai laici",
  editor     = "G. D'Elia",
  publisher      = "Egea -- Università Bocconi Editori",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2009",
  pages      = "61-74",
}

@book{ fornero:2012,
  author         = "Giovanni Fornero and Maurizio Mori",
  title          = "Laici e cattolici in bioetica: storia e teoria di un confronto",
  publisher      = "Le Lettere",
  location       = "Firenze",
  year           = "2012",
}

@book{ giordano:1997,
  author         = "Giuseppe Giordano",
  title          = "Tra paradigmi e rivoluzioni. Thomas Kuhn",
  publisher      = "Rubbettino",
  location       = "Soveria Mannelli",
  year           = "1997",
}

@book{ hoyningen:1993,
  author         = "Paul Hoyningen-Huene",
  title          = "Recontructing Scientific Revolutions",
  publisher      = "The University of Chicago Press",
  location       = "Chicago",
  year           = "1993",
}

@book{ kuhn:1982,
  author         = "Thomas Kuhn",
  title          = "La struttura delle rivoluzioni scientifiche",
  publisher      = "Einaudi",
  location       = "Torino",
  year           = "1982",
}

@inbook{ masterman:1980,
  author         = "Mary Masterman",
  title          = "La natura di un paradigma",
  maintitle  = "Critica e crescita della conoscenza",
  editor     = "Imre Lakatos and Alan Musgrave",
  publisher      = "Feltrinelli",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "1980",
  edition    = "3",
  pages      = "129-163",
}

@inbook{ mcmullin:1993,
  author         = "Ernan McMullin",
  title          = "Rationality and Paradigm Change in Science",
  maintitle  = "World Changes",
  editor     = "Paul Hprwich",
  publisher      = "The MIT Press",
  location       = "Cambridge (Massachusetts)",
  year           = "1993",
  pages      = "55-78",
}

@book{ siegel:1987,
  author         = "Harvey Siegel",
  title          = "Relativism Refuted",
  publisher      = "Reidel",
  location       = "Dordrecht",
  year           = "1987",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Il concetto di paradigma in Kuhn}
È largamente note che il concetto kuhniano di paradigma -- così come definito e
adottato ne \emph{La struttura delle rivoluzioni scientifiche} del 1962 -- è
stato alla base di significative innovazioni \footcite[23]{kuhn:1982} anche nel
metodo storiografico, almeno applicato alla storia della scienza, ma insieme
che, da subito, è stato oggetto di numerose critiche per le sue ambiguità
e difficoltà.

In realtà, la nozione di paradigma matura gradualmente nella produzione
dell'epistemologo attraverso la sua monografia \emph{La rivoluzione copernicana}
del 1957 e trova approfondimenti teorici e affinamenti storiografici nella sua
produzione successiva.

Fra i primi a rilevare analiticamente le ambiguità e le oscillazioni del
concetto kuhniano di paradigma, 

La caratteristica che svariati epistemologi e storici della scienza hanno
apprezzato e condiviso, ma dove risiede anche la maggior parte delle difficoltà
sia intrinseche, sia nell'utilizzo ulteriore della mozione kuhniana di paradigma
è il suo sfondo realistico (in cui si muove peraltro tutta la riflessione dello
stesso Kuhn. Fra le accezioni di paradigma che si intrecciano confusamente vi
sarebbero quella di «un'intera tradizione e un modello»\footcite[133]{masterman:1980}
    
\section{Il concetto di paradigma in Fornero}
Nell'approccio di Fornero\footcite[23]{fornero:2009a} il concetto di paradigma
è adottato per esplorare l'ambito vasto ed eterogeneo delle posizioni della
bioetica contemporanea.

La prima definizione offerta da Fornero chiarisce il paradigma come «la
posizione»\footcite[37]{fornero:2009a}

In seguito Fornero compie un approfondimento metodologico che lo porta ad
approfondire la prima definizione: il paradigma sarebbe in questa rinnovata
definizione «l'individuazione»
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So, whay I've further to modify? Thanx

==============================================

Post Scriptum

Try your own code in this case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[type1]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\usepackage{textcase}

%%% BIBLIOGRAFIA
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,scauthors=true,scauthorscite=true,%
classical=true,firstinits=true,commacit=true,volnumformat=strings,volumeformat=romansc,%
sorting=nyt,citepages=omit,indexing]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % in corsivo tutti i titoli
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}} % riviste tra virgolette caporali
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}} % riviste tra virgolette caporali
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize} % riduce il font della bibliografia

\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\iftoggle{bbx:scauthors}{%
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
     \ifblank{#3#5}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}%
  {}}%

\DeclareNameFormat{scdefault}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}
  
% mantiene il nome autore nelle citazioni successiva alla prima
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{% 
\ifcase\value{uniquename}% 
\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
 \or 
 \ifuseprefix 
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}} 
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
 \or
 \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}% 
\fi 
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ fornero:2008,
  author         = "Giovanni Fornero",
  title          = "Laicita debole e laicita forte",
  publisher      = "B. Mondadori",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2008",
}

@book{ fornero:2009,
  author         = "Giovanni Fornero",
  title          = "Bioetica cattolica e bioetica laica",
  publisher      = "B. Mondadori",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2009",
  edition    = "2",
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Nell'approccio di Fornero\footcite[23]{fornero:2008} il concetto

Il paradigma la posizione\footcite[37]{fornero:2009}

Nell'approccio di Fornero\footcite[23]{fornero:2008} il concetto

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,classical=true,scauthors = true, scauthorscite, %
firstinits=true,volnumformat=strings,volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,%
indexing]{biblatex}
    \nocite{*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ bertelli:2012,
       author = {Lucio Bertelli},
       title = {Tra storia e utopia},
       publisher = {Edizioni dell'Orso},
       location = {Alessandria},
       year = {2012},
     }
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

 \AtBeginBibliography{%
 \iftoggle{bbx:scauthors}{%
 \DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
 \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
 \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
 \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
 \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
 \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
 {\iffirstinits
 {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
 {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
 \ifblank{#3#5}
 {}
 {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
 {\iffirstinits
 {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
 {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}%
 \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}%
 {}}%

\DeclareNameFormat{scdefault}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{bertelli:2012}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx, working very fine! In the while, I tried another solution. However it loses the first name:

Comment: `\AtEveryCite{
\DeclareNameFormat{scdefault}{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textlcsc}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textlcsc}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}%
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}`

Comment: What do you mean with this code?

Comment: with that code I obtain scshape, but I lost the name: so I've `BERTELLI` but not `BERTELLI L`. moreover, from some tries I realized that with your code the occurrences of name following the first one have again the uppercase and are not all in scshape :(

Comment: @user41063: I'll see what I can do for this issue. One thing is not clear to me: do you want the forename to appear in citations or not?

Comment: Yes, I want. But both forename and surname all in scshape in the whole text. thanx!